# convert div to single image with canvas-javascript css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to convert content div below to a single image downloadable How is the piece with the canvas or other code after convert show Download Image button
how i do it

```css
 #content{
          position: absolute;
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          border: 5px solid red;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      #img1{
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
                 position: absolute;
          z-index: 5;
    
      }
      #img2{
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 6;
          
           width: 150px;
          height: 190px;
      }
      #img3{
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 7;
          width: 200px;
          height: 100px;
          
          
      }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <img id="img1" src="http://www.completeleasing.co.uk/media/sector%20images/software-2.jpg">
    <img id="img2" src="http://www.ipwatchdog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/programing-software.jpg">
     <img id="img3" src=" http://www.sikich.com/blog/image.axd?picture=%2F2014%2F04%2FTeam.jpg">
   
    </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="convert div to image"><br>
    <h3>result:</h3>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [html2canvas library](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) for this. Make sure you set `allowTaint` to `true` so that it renders the cross-origin images as well. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3u3nk19/) for an example.

The `html2canvas` function returns a promise that provides a `<canvas>` element which you can put wherever you want to display the rendered image. You can then treat it like you would any other canvas, including right-clicking it to download as an image.

[This updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3u3nk19/1/) includes a link to download the image. Keep in mind that this only works in browsers that support the `download` attribute on `a` tags.

Comment: great answer thank you sir but you can add button to save result image

Comment: @JackKing I've edited my answer to include the download button.

Comment: After pressing the loading and when I do I open the image location loading .. picture does not open

Comment: @JackKing My mistake; tainted canvases can't be exported via `.toDataURL()`. In order to download the canvas as an image you will have to host all the images on the same domain as the HTML file.

Comment: Can you solve this problem .. because i used in mobile so i need button to download :(

Comment: @JackKing Are you hosting this page on a website that you are accessing from a mobile device? If so, download your three images into the same folder as the page and update the `<img>` URLs appropriately. This should fix the problem.

Comment: when i download result image without hosting he downloaded (index.html ).. when i download result with hosing he downloaded with( my_image.png )but do not opened .. show msg (invalid open image) with picasa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120643/discussion-between-hydrothermal-and-jack-king).

Answer (score 1):

Download and import this JS file to the page where you need to convert div to image. [Link](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js)

Image format can be changed to PNG or JPG.

Use the below function on onclick functionality.

```
var tagName = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-div-tag").id;
html2canvas(document.getElementById(tagName)).then(function (canvas) {
    var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);
    anchorTag.download = "Picture.png";
    anchorTag.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    anchorTag.target = '_blank';
    anchorTag.click();
});
```

Reference link: https://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png