# downloading image from website to desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone please explain to me. Why my this code is not working? I have changed my code over and over and its hard to explain what is not working. So i finally put it in my website so I can show you what is going on. Here is where i found the code: [convert div to single image with canvas-javascript css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882656/convert-div-to-single-image-with-canvas-javascript-css) I use this an example because I'm trying to do the same thing. I changed the images so you can see on my site https://torcdesign.com/mom.php

```js
var download = document.getElementById("download"),
  result = document.getElementById("result");

function renderContent() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"), {
        allowTaint: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      result.appendChild(canvas);
        download.style.display = "inline";
    });
}

function downloadImage() {
  download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL("image/png");
}

document.getElementById("button").onclick = renderContent;
download.onclick = downloadImage
```

```css
<style>
#content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#img1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}

#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;

    width: 150px;
    height: 190px;
}

#img3 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 7;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#download {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
    <img id="img1" src="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/brown.jpg">
    <img id="img2" src="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/kiwi.jpg">
    <img id="img3" src="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/lswhite.jpg">   
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input id="button" type="button" value="convert div to image"><br>
<h3>result:</h3>
<div id="result"></div>
<a id="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a>
```

Comment: Is your issue that on your website your image is not encoded properly?

Comment: Have you tried downloading after converting to image?

Comment: @bugfroggy I changed my code I'm sorry but still won't work either way

Comment: @calliber Yes, and your image isn't encoded properly. This is because your href isn't being changed when you click on the download link for some reason (It's still `#`). Therefore, it's downloading the source of the entire page rather than just the image. Not sure, why, still investigating.

Comment: How can I Fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, it looks like the issue is that your canvas is tainted, and you cannot export a tainted canvas. To make sure you canvas is not tainted, you cannot use cross-origin images. For example, I tried using a base-64 encoded image instead, and that one worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to give me an example ?

Comment: What worked for me was just changing the image sources to something else that doesn't taint it, like a base-64 encoded image: `data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: Thank you I appreciate  your help